# D3.js on("drag") called even when I just click a node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I've been working with the example on directed graphs here - http://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459.

Here, there is a on drag function in the JS code (graph-creator.js)-

```
.on("drag", function(args){
        thisGraph.state.justDragged = true;
        thisGraph.dragmove.call(thisGraph, args);
      })
```

Most of the time, this works as expected. But sometimes, the browser seems to get stuck in a state where the function is called even if I simply click the node. Since this seems to be a native event, I don't know how to tweak this to make sure it doesn't happen. Does any one have a suggestion on why this is happening and what I can do to make this function robust?

Comment: It will be a very wild guess...can you put up a working fiddle and explain better as to where/when it breaks.

Comment: So, right now the working code on the link I pasted (with the demo graph) doesn't select a node when I click on it (so I can't delete it). It's very strange because this issue seems to happen at random (other times, the functionality works fine). I wouldn't be surprised if you tried it and were able to click and delete a node on your browser. JS fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/n9gp9r8j/

Comment: I added alert statements on lines 382 and 386 of the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/n9gp9r8j/. When I click a node without moving it at all (on chrome), it still says dragged.

Comment: Ok yes the function drag will be called even if you do mouse down...coz its tied to mouse down event.
But why not set the flag off on `drag end` callback thisGraph.state.justDragged = true;